# How to specify the route Groups?startIndex={startIndex}&count={count} for azure functions

Tags: azure-functions

How to specify the route for the azure function in a below format

Groups?startIndex={startIndex}&count={count}

Answer (score 0):

As the same question already discussed in the [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/757230/how-to-specify-34amp34-operation-in-azure-function.html), thanks to [Mayank Bargali](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/mayankbargali-msft/) - Posting your answer to help other community members:

> You can only define `string` value as the Route property is of type
> string.   As per your requirement, you can define the Route as below
> and to get the query parameter you can leverage `HttpRequest` object
> `Query` parameter. For more details on the route parameter and query
> string please refer to [this
> document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#using-route-parameters).
>
> ```
> Route = "tc2/users/Groups/{id:int?}"
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> I have used the below C# code for testing purposes.
>
> 1. `public  static  async  Task<IActionResult>  Run(`
> 2. `[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,  "get",  "post",  Route  =  "tc2/users/Groups/{id:int?}")]  HttpRequest req,  int? id,`
> 3. `ILogger log)`
> 4. `{`
> 5. `log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");`
> 6. `int startIndex, count;`
> 7. `if  (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Query["startIndex"]))`
> 8. `startIndex =  int.Parse(req.Query["startIndex"]);`
> 9. `if  (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Query["count"]))`
> 10. `count =  int.Parse(req.Query["count"]);`
> 11. `return  new  OkObjectResult("Ok");`
> 12. `}`
>
> **Note:** The above is only for reference and please update it as per your business needs and handle the exception while converting the
> query parameter.